# SQL to return one row for each distinct value of a column (do not mind which row)

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column named X. X contains number from 0 to 99. But there are duplicates (e.g. 0 is there multiple times! )

Now I need a query that gives any of the rows with 0,1,2,3...99 meaning I get 100 results at with one query, but I don't care which of the x==0 , x==1 ... I get, but just one of them!

Is there such thing in sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select distinct x
from your_table
```

To get a complete record you can group by the `X` column. But you have to tell the DB which of the duplicate values of the other columns you want.

```
 select x, min(y) as y
 from your_table
 group by x
```

If you build a group by `X` then this value will be distinct. For the other columns you need a so called aggregate function like for example `min()`. That tells the DB to pick the minimum `Y` of every `X` group.

Comment: Can I get a whole row with this?

Comment: You can get different rows for that. But if the values differ for the other columns then you will get all `x`s. But if the other values of the record differ and you don't care which one you get then why get them anyway?

Comment: Sry, I dont understand your comment ^^. E.g. I need (any) entire row where x==0 (and x==1....) [(x==0,y==17),(x==1,y==5),...]

Comment: Join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55823/sql-query-complicated-where-statement

Comment: Works very nicely! I didn't even need the min(y). Thats one short follow up: is it possible to get more than one row per group?

Comment: Yes, but the implementation depends on the DB engine you use and could be complicated.

Comment: What exactly is this y in your statement? and why is there no DISTINCT keyword? sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @Sajuuk: `y` is an alias name for the column since `min(y)` is not a great name for a column. and you do not need  `distinct` when you `group`.